# Product of all Square Roots, taken only Decimal Digits

Tags: recreational-mathematics, computational-mathematics, products

How and where could I compute the **decimal reminder** of a product of square roots times ten:

$$Dr\left( \prod_{x=1}^{k}x^\frac{1}{2} \right) \times 10$$

Where $k$ is a power of $10$.

I would like to be able to generate a table of values as $k$ approaches $\infty$.

I tryed using [wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/) but it gets stuck when computing $k>5$.

---

This is interesting for me since I noticed that for $k=1,2,3,4,5$ we have:
$$\approx9,4$$
$$\approx6,6$$
$$\approx3,4$$
$$\approx3,3$$
$$\approx3,14$$

Which seems to approach $\pi$?

Or is this just a coincidence, and the values have a different pattern when considering more values of $k$?

Anyhow, I would want to be able to compute a table of those values somehow.

---

The $k$ is a power of $10$ since if it was not a power of $10$, then the final result could vary and seems to not follow a pattern, for example if $k$ was $10^5\pm1$ then the result is $\approx 6,8$ .

But since $k$ is a power of ten, it seems to be stable in a sense of tending to $\pi$ but only for the first $5$ values so far, since I couldn't find a way to compute the next one.

As far as I know, all of this is most likely a coincidence?

Anyway, I need a more efficient way to compute this final value since I want to explore its properties. (And with the help of that then later likely explore similar expressions in a sense of taking out the decimal part of the number in some way.)

Comment: Please clarify: Do you want to compute $10\sqrt{10^n!}$ for $k=10^n?$ How do you get the given values? Or what is *decimal reminder*?

Comment: @gammatester I'm calculating the decimal part of $\sqrt{10^n!}$ times $10$, for example if $n=3$, we have $\approx 6.34\times10^{1283}$, the decimal part/remainder of that would be $\approx0.34$, and times $10$ is the $\approx3,4$ as I listed it in the third value for $k=3$.

Comment: @Matta, $\sqrt{10!}=1904.94094...\approx1.90\times10^3$, so, in analogy with your explanation for $k=3$, you should get $9.0$, not $9.4$, for $k=1$.  It looks to me like you might be changing the meaning of "decimal part" when you get to large numbers that are represented in scientific notation.

Comment: @BarryCipra I took the scientific approximation since it wouldn't expand large values, all in all those are rough estimations anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you want the leading-order digits, starting from the second one, of $\sqrt{n!}$, where $n$ is a power of ten.  Stirling's approximation will give you what you need.  Specifically, use
$$
n! \sim n^n e^{-n}\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(1 + \frac{1}{12n}\right).
$$
If $n=10^k$, then $n^n$ is a large even power of $10$ and its square root doesn't affect the decimal digits.  So the leading-order digits you want are the same as the ones in
$$
e^{-n/2}\sqrt[4]{2\pi n}.
$$
According to WolframAlpha, taking $n=10^2,10^3,\ldots$ gives leading-order digits of $9.66$, $6.343$, $5.335$, $5.314$, $2.875$, $3.468$, $\ldots$.  So the apparent pattern of convergence to $\pi$ from $k=3,4,5$ does not continue to $k=6$.